# How can I use span to create a burger-menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This won't work for a reason, I think with by using DIV is a different story, could someone please enlighten me? Many thanks!

```css
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger-menu">
  <span class="bar1">1</span>
  <span class="bar2">2</span>
  <span class="bar3">3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default span elements are `inline`, you can't apply height and width to `inline` elements. In order to apply height and width, you either make them as `block` or `inline-block`.

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3{
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: black;
   display:block
}
```

In addition to this, in this video I've explained how you can make hamburger menu using only one `div` with animation.
https://youtu.be/Y2yW1-QYQco

Comment: That's the explanation I was looking for. Many thanks bro!